# IndexedSeq VS. PersistentVector

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Can somebody explain me, the difference between 'IndexedSeq' and 'PersistentVector'?

I bumped into this, when updating a vector in my data structure via 'rest'. Here's a REPL excerpt that shows the transformation.

```
=> (def xs [1 2 3])
...
(type xs)
cljs.core/PersistentVector
=> (def xs2 (rest xs))
...
(type xs2)
cljs.core/IndexedSeq
```

I'm holding a list in an app-state atom, which needs to be shifted once in a while, so the first item must disappear. Would be really cool, if anybody could give me a hint about which data structure might be preferable here in terms of performance.
Sometimes elements get pushed to the end of the list as well, so I guess it's a LIFO mechanism that I'm creating here.

Answer (score 1):

From your last paragraph, it sounds like you're using this as a stack.  Taken together, `pop`, `peek`, and `conj` form a stack interface that can be used with either lists or vectors (working on the front of a list or the end of a vector).  I would use those.

If you're just using those functions, I don't think there should be any significant performance differences (all three functions should be constant time).

Comment: Close, but since he's adding to one end and removing from the other, this is a queue, not a stack. So rather than using a vector or a list, PersistentQueue is the right type, but pop/peek/conj are still the right operations.

Comment: @amalloy A queue is FIFO, not LIFO.  I think the "end" he's referring to in the question is the front.  Anton, can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

looking at the superinterfaces here: http://static.javadoc.io/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clojure/lang/IndexedSeq.html
I can guess, it is not the most efficient thing here, since it is just a seq, with no guaranteed constant-time access to the nth member. To ensure the vector semantics you should probably use `subvec` to remove the first element.

In general, if you don't do random access to elements, **in terms of performance** it should be enough to use `concat` to add element to the end (as it produces a lazy sequence, won't consume the whole collection, and should be done in a constant time) and `rest` to remove the first element (as it is also done in a constant time), to make FIFO stack (which is what you do). (it's not the best variant still, since it may lead to stack owerflow, if you do alot of `push` without realizing the sequence.

But sure it's better to use vectors. So the combination of `conj` , `first`, and `subvec` should be your choice.

Comment: by random access you mean accessing other elements than the first or the last? The only write manipulations are adding to the end and removing from the beginning. I'm reading the sequence as a whole: from the first to the last element.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i mean. So, as far as i know, the difference between `subvec` and `rest` in your case is the `conj` semantics. If you use `conj` to add a last element: `(conj (rest [1 2 3]) 1) => (4 2 3)` , `(conj (subvec [1 2 3] 1) 4) => [2 3 4]`

Comment: in general you shouldn't rely on interfaces of collections returned by a function call (because they all could be subject to change in next versions of clojure). You should rather check if they satisfy some predicates like `counted?` , `reversible?` , `associative?` and so on.